# Reduce array by adding elements

Tags: algorithm

I came across this question in a test.

**Given an array, reduce the array to a single element with minimum cost. For reducing, remove two elements from the array, add those two numbers and keep the sum back in the array. The cost of each operation is the sum of the elements removed in that step.**

Example, let the array `A = [1,2,3]`

Then, we can remove 1 and 2, add both of them and keep the sum back in array. Cost of this step would be (1+2) = 3.

So A = [3,3], Cost = 3

In second step, we can remove both elements from the array and keep the sum back in array again. Cost of this step would be 3 + 3 = 6.

So, A = [6], Cost = 6

So total cost turns out to be 9 (6+3).

I tried sorting the array, and adding the elements from decreasing to increasing, but it fails if there are duplicate elements.

Pseudo code of my algorithm

```
sort(Array)
cost = 0
for(i=0; i<Array.length - 1; i++) {
   Array[i+1] = Array[i] + Array[i+1]
   cost = cost + Array[i+1]
}
```

The algorithm mentioned above was not working. I came up with a possible case where it may fail.
If the Array = [5, 5, 5, 5], then Cost = 45, according to the above algorithm.

However if we sum the first two elements and last two elements, and then sum the remaining two elements, then the total cost turns out to be 40. (In first step, cost = 10*2, and in next step another 20)

What could be a efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: I think always adding the two smallest elements should work. Are you doing this? Please show the exact algorithm you are using. When you add the sum back into the array, do you put it in the front, the back, or where it belongs w.r.t. the sorting?

Comment: I have edited the question. I am saving the sum back into the array in front (replacing one of the element with the sum). I thought keeping the sum back into the array in proper place  w.r.t. sorting would be a little time consuming, as I need to do it after every replacement.

Comment: Perhaps you should hold the elements in a heap or binary search tree? Then it will only cost O(logn) to retrieve the two smallest elements each time.

Comment: Huh? What am I missing? If the cost is the sum of the two elements removed and, afterwards, the sum is added back anyway, then the total cost of "reducing" the entire array is actually the sum of all elements, and this will be regardless of the order of individual reducing!! Is the problem well described?

Comment: can we insert anywhere in the array? are we not considering the cost of insertion into array; considering we might need to move elements?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Since we are keeping the sum back, if we start with a larger one, we'll end up adding it multiple times in the overall cost, thereby increasing the cost which may have reduced by starting with a smaller element.

Comment: Is it possible to have a linear time solution to this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were on the right track with sorting the array and summing the lowest elements first. The problem is: The sum of the two lowest elements could be greater than the next element after those, so you can't just put it in the front. But it can also be smaller than the last element, so you can't put it in the back, either. You have to put the sum into just the place it belongs w.r.t. the sorting.

Example: If your list is `[1, 1, 3, 3]`, then `1+1` should be put in the front, i.e. `[2, 3, 3]`, but if we have `[2, 2, 3, 3]`, then the sum `2+2` has to be put in the back `[3, 3, 4]`, and for `[2, 2, 3, 5]` is has to be put in the middle position, i.e. `[3, 4, 5]`.

A simple way to do this is using a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) structure. Those are available in most languages and provide methods for getting and removing the smallest element, and for inserting an element in the right place.<sup>1</sup> Here's an example in Python:

```py
import heapq
def reduce_sum(lst):
    heapq.heapify(lst)
    s = 0
    while len(lst) > 1:
        first = heapq.heappop(lst)
        second = heapq.heappop(lst)
        s += first + second
        heapq.heappush(lst, first + second)
    return s

reduce_sum([1,2,3])      # 9
reduce_sum([5, 5, 5, 5]) # 40
```

And if you can not use Heaps, you can still iterate the array to find the right place to put the summed element, or use binary search to do so faster, but even then the insertion-step will be O(n) for an overall complexity of O(n²), whereas it's only O(n logn) using a heap.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Technically, the heap will *not* insert the element in "the right place", but just maintain the *heap invariant*, which is all you need for this problem, since you always access the smallest elements.

Answer (score 3):

You array will be always reduces to the `sum` of all its elements. The `"cost`" of this reduction may vary though.
The minimum `"cost"` could be achieved by adding two minimum elements that currently exist in the array.

Min heap can be used to solve this problem very efficiently. Here's an example in java.

```
    public int[] sumAndCost(Integer[] arr) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        int sum = priorityQueue.poll();
        int cost = 0;
        while (!priorityQueue.isEmpty()) {
            int currentElement = priorityQueue.poll();
            if (currentElement < sum) {
                priorityQueue.add(sum);
                sum = currentElement;
            } else {
                sum += currentElement;
                cost += sum;
                continue;
            }

            sum += priorityQueue.poll();
            cost += sum;
        }

        return new int[] {sum, cost};
    }
```

It returns both the sum and the cost for any given array.

Conditional statement may seen a bit uncessary but it somewhat improves our runtime.

Answer (score 2):

PriorityQueue is an unbounded queue based on a priority heap and the elements of the priority queue are ordered by default in natural order.[1]

The head of the priority queue is the least element based on the natural ordering or comparator based ordering, if there are multiple objects with same ordering, then it can poll any one of them randomly. When we poll the queue, it returns the head object from the queue.[1]

So if we take an example where array `arr[] =  [5,5,5,5,5]` 
Here is how it will work:

**Note: The below iteration is for demonstration purpose only. The PriorityQueue may not have same ordering but it makes sure to give the minimum element when it is polled**

```
Queue         : 5 5 5 5 5

Iteration 1   : 5 5 5 10 :- Cost: 10
Iteration 2   : 5 10 10  :- Cost: 10 + 10 = 20
Iteration 3   : 10 15    :- Cost: 20 + 15 = 35 
Iteration 4   : 25       :- Cost: 35 + 25 = 60
```

```
public static int min_cost(int[] arr)
{
    PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    //adding all the elements to the queue
    for(Integer i : arr)
    {
        queue.offer(i);
    }
    int temp = 0;
    int cost = 0;
    while(queue.size() > 1)
    {
        // Removing the first two minimum elements from the queue
        int first = queue.poll();
        int second = queue.poll();
        temp = first + second;
        cost += temp;

        //Adding back the sum of the minimum elements back to the queue
        queue.offer(temp);
    }
    return cost;
}
```

Reference:
[1] https://www.journaldev.com/1642/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example

Answer (score 2):

First, sort the array.

Second, loop this step until only two elements remain in the array.

- Get a new value by summing the first two elements of the array
- Put this new value into the array at the proper position

Third, return the sum of two elements that are remained in the array.

```js
function sortedIndex(array, value) {
  let low = 0, high = array.length;

  while (low < high) {
    let mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
    if (array[mid] < value) low = mid + 1;
    else high = mid;
  }
  return low;
}

function reductionCost(num) {
  let cost = 0;
  num.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  });

  while (num.length > 2) {
    const newValue = num.shift() + num.shift();
    cost += newValue;
    const newIndex = sortedIndex(num, newValue);
    num.splice(newIndex, 0, newValue);
  }
  return cost + num[0] + num[1];
}

console.log(reductionCost([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(reductionCost([5, 5, 5, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @tobias_k for fantastic explanation.My solution using just list,

`

```
def reduction(num):
    a= []
    cost = 0
    while len(num) > 1:
        first = num.pop(0)
        second = num.pop(0)
        cost += first + second
        num = [first+second] + num
    print(cost)
```

`

Comment: It's not correct. Example input that produces wrong result: [2, 2, 3, 3]. Lowest cost is 20 and your code returns 21

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in java:

```
int cost = 0;
for (int i=1; i<Array.length; i++) {
    Array[i] += Array[i-1];
    cost += Array[i];
}
return cost;
```

Comment: Please add description.

Comment: [1,2,3,4] -> Array.
You start at index 1 which will 2 from the array.
You will then add the previous value to the current one. i.e. Add 1 to 2 = 3. So now the new value at index 1 is 3.
You then add that value to score.  
With each iteration: the current value at the index is added to the one from the previous index. The new value is then added to cost.

1st iterations: [1,3,3,4], cost = 3
2nd: [1,3,6,4], cost = 9
3rd: [1,3,6,10] , cost = 19
e.t.c.

Comment: It's not correct. Example inputs that produce wrong result: { 3, 2, 1 } or { 2, 2, 3, 3}

Answer (score 0):

```
#
# Complete the 'reductionCost' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY num as parameter.
#
from bisect import insort
def makeReduction(num):
    first = num[0]
    second = num[1]
    cost = first+second
    del num[:2]
    insort(num,cost)
    return cost

def reductionCost(num):
    # Write your code here
    if len(num) <= 1:
        return 0
    num.sort()
    totalCost = 0
    while len(num) >= 2:
        totalCost += makeReduction(num)
        print(totalCost)
        len(num)
    return totalCost
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this, I cant say it take the least time and memory but it will give correct solution.

```
def reduction(num):
cost = 0
while len(num) > 1:
    num.sort()
    first = num.pop(0)
    second = num.pop(0)
    cost += first + second
    num.append(cost)
return cost
```

Answer (score 0):

### Since the aim is to reduce the cost, we have to sort the array on each iteration.

```js
function reductionCost(num) {
  let cost = 0;

  while (num.length > 2) {

    num.sort((a, b) => {
      return a - b;
    });

    const newValue = num.shift() + num.shift();
    cost += newValue;
    num.splice(num.length, 0, newValue);
  }
  return cost + num[0] + num[1];
}

console.log(reductionCost([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this, I cant say it take the least time and memory but it will give correct solution.

If the data in the `Arraylist`, then used below code.

```
public class ReductionCost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(5);

        Integer cost = 0;

        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> list2 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(list);

        for (Integer data : list2) {

            if (list2.size() > 2) {
                cost = reduceCst(list2, cost);

            } else if (list2.size() == 2) {
                cost = reduceCst(list2, cost);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(cost);

    }

    public static Integer reduceCst(List<Integer> list, int cost) {

        if (list.size() == 1) {
            cost = cost + list.get(0);
        } else {

            int totalCost = list.get(0) + list.get(1);
            cost = cost + totalCost;
            list.remove(0);
            list.remove(0);
            list.add(totalCost);
        }

        return cost;

    }
}
```